# Updating database based on selected check boxes

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code to generate dynamic check boxes in my view:

```
@foreach (var sub in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   value="@sub.Id" 
                   name="Profile.InterestIds"
                   checked="@sub.IsChecked"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @sub.Title
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In this application we are using soft-delete mechanism so if user unchecked an item, We just set `IsDeleted` to `true` using `_memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);`. Here's the code for doing this process:

```
public override void Update(UserProfileDto item)
{
    // Getting all Member Interests (where IsDeleted == true)
    var memberIntersestIds = _memberInterestService.GetAllPlusDeleted();
    // List of ids in the database as Guid
    var dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
    var union = dbIds.ToList().Union(item.InterestIds);

    // item.InterestIds is IEnumerable<Guid> (selected check boxes)
    if (item.InterestIds != null)
    {
        var guids = union as Guid[] ?? union.ToArray();
        foreach (var id in guids)
            if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);

        foreach (var id in guids)
        {
            if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
                _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
                {
                    UserProfileId = item.Id,
                    InterestSubCategoryId = id
                });
            else
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
        }
    }
    else
        foreach (var memberInterest in memberIntersestIds)
            _memberInterestService.Delete(memberInterest.InterestSubCategoryId, item.Id, true);
}
```

This code works fine until user unchecked one of the check box after submitting the form nothing happens, this code doesn't remove the unchecked item from the database. Any idea?

**Update**: I got the code working , by changing the foreach loop to a for loop, because each check box's id needs to be unique:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="@i" 
                   value="@Model.ElementAt(i).Id" 
                   name="Profile.InterestIds" 
                   class = "interest-checkbox" 
                   checked="@Model.ElementAt(i).IsChecked"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Model.ElementAt(i).Title
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Then I changed the method from using `Union` to `Except`: ([also used this suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152362/18444))

```
public override void Update(UserProfileDto item)
{
    var memberIntersestIds = _memberInterestService.GetMyInterestsExceptDeleted(item.Id);
    if (item.InterestIds != null)
    {
        var dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
        var guids = dbIds.ToList().Except(item.InterestIds).ToArray();
        foreach (var id in guids)
        {
            if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id, item.Id))
            {
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
            }
            else
            {
                _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
                {
                    UserProfileId = item.Id,
                    InterestSubCategoryId = id
                });
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var memberInterest in memberIntersestIds)
        {
            _memberInterestService.Delete(memberInterest.InterestSubCategoryId, item.Id, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can unchecked items, but it doesn't checked them back, because they exist in the database and their `IsDeleted` is set to `1`.

Comment: Can not make out from the code that how do you determine at the server if the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya If check boxes are checked, the model binder gives me their value, otherwise they would be `null`

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like you have one name `name="Profile.InterestIds"` for all of your checkboxes. That might be an issue.

Comment: This process works for adding new items, the problem is that, when user want to unchecked one item, nothing happens.

Comment: what does it mean "nothing happens"? If user unchecks one item, you are not getting it as null?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, In fact it will not unchecked the item after submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain it is because of your double foreach loops

> ```
>     foreach (var id in guids)
>         if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>             _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
>
>     foreach (var id in guids)
>     {
>         if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>             _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
>             {
>                 UserProfileId = item.Id,
>                 InterestSubCategoryId = id
>             });
>         else
>             _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
>     }
> ```

the first one deletes all the data, and the second one adds the data back in.

Your code currently deletes everything that existed, then adds the stuff that does not exist or deletes what does still exist.

this code does not make sense to me.  I read it like this

> go through the ids and delete everything that exists, now nothing
>   exists in `_memberInterestService`
>
> Then go through all the ids again and add everything that does not
>   exist, if something does still exist, delete it so it does not exist
>   anymore

Comment: This code deletes all the existing items stored in the database, by delete I mean `_memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);`

Comment: your code currently deletes everything that existed, then adds the stuff that does not exist or deletes what does still exist...